# Cell height is way too small after using UITableViewAutomaticDimension for static cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

After using `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` for static cells (which are 'right detail cell's, so I can't set any constraint to cell's height)

the cells' heights became way to small. Is there any way to fix this? :(

Thanks in advance!

[What I was expecting(image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Grkp.png)

[How it shows(image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZP0D.png)

codes :

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 65
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 65
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

**EDIT:**

It seemed like there is no way to extend height without `constraint`s when using `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` so I set `rowHeight` manually :

```
struct DeviceSize {
    static let iPhoneSE = (width:Float(320.0), height:Float(568.0))
    static let iPhone7 = (width: Float(375.0), height:Float(667.0))
    static let iPhone7P = (width: Float(414.0), height:Float(736.0))
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
               heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let height = Float(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height)
    switch height {
    case DeviceSize.iPhoneSE.height:
        return 55
    case DeviceSize.iPhone7.height:
        return 60
    case DeviceSize.iPhone7P.height:
        return 65
    default:
        return 65
    }
}
```

Comment: tableView.estimatedRowHeight =  UITableViewAutomaticDimension
 tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

Comment: Put a breakpoint and check, is that methods get called or not..

Comment: @VibhaSingh I just tried your code and it seems like it doesn't work..

Comment: @VigneshDavins I already checked and the methods got called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use automatic dimension then the cell height will be automatically calculated.Set row height manually.

These lines not required

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 65
}
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 65
   tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

**Solution :**

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if indexPath.row == 0{
    //.... return height whatever you want for indexPath.row
    return 40
    }else {
    return 30
    }
}
```

Comment: Basically the reason why I tried to use UITableViewAutomaticDimension is to adjust cell height for iPhone SE(cell was too big on iPhone SE but it is looking nice on iPhone 6,7..et cetera). So unfortunately setting constant value for each of rows won't work. I could get screen ratio from UIScreen and set cell height manually but I thought It is kinda messy so I was wondering if there is any solution with UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Answer (score 2):

Inside the cell, Set the label with a height Constraint `Greater than or Equal` to minimum height required. `AutomaticDimensions` make the cell height depending on the text content of label. Just give the label a minimum height like [image: this]

Comment: Thanks but like I said I can't set constraints for the title label inside of Right Detail cell. I think this solution would work on custom cells.